# Discord Py bot spams channel when looping through a dictionary

Tags: loops, dictionary, python-3.6, python-asyncio, discord

```
import asyncio
import random
import discord

memes = {
    'r/dank_memes': {'imgur_url':'https://imgur.com/r/dankmemes/', 'trigger': 'get dank', 'memes':['get dank meme', 'sample meme']},
    'r/cats': {'imgur_url':'https://imgur.com/r/cats/', 'trigger': 'meow', 'memes':['cat meme', 'i love cats']},
    }

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    message.content = message.content.lower()

    for name, trigger in memes.items():
        if trigger['trigger'] in message.content:
            #print(random.choice(memes[name]['memes'])) # This works fine
            await client.send_message(message.channel, random.choice(memes[name]['memes']))
```

I am making a discord bot that posts random memes I scraped online when a certain keyword is said in my channel.

My problem is that when I type "get dank" in discord the bot will spam a bunch of memes:

```
get dank meme
get dank meme
dank 2
get dank meme
```

But when I type "meow" or whatever the last value is in the memes dictionary then it works fine and only sends one image.

I have figured out that this has something to do the `await` from asyncio because when I use print() it only sends its once to the console. It appears the `await` is required though because the script won't do anything without it. Using break in the for loop doesn't help either.

Is there a way to make the loop stop once it found a keyword or to only have it send one image and using the `await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be that one of your sample memes, `get dank meme`, contains the trigger itself. A new `on_message` picks it up, and responds with a new meme, which can again contain the trigger, and so on. That doesn't happen with `print` because `print` does not transmit to the channel and therefore cannot trigger meme responses.

To fix this, either be careful to avoid triggers in your meme responses, or include code that ignores triggers coming from the bot itself.

Comment: That makes so much sense. I should've known.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Xaztek The way most people get around this is by including a `if message.author == client.user: return` check